# How to set a default value for Date column to "Today's Date"

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script to add a date type column with "Today's Date" as the default value. How I can set it up?

```
$list | new-spjfield "Date" -internalname "Date" -type DateTime -dateformat DateOnly -Defaultvalue "[Today]"
```

Above command sets default to static date/time of today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **[today]**

I created following script and its working fine

```
$spSite = Get-SPSite -Identity http://test
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb()     
$lList=$spWeb.Lists["testlist"]  
$lList.Fields.Add("Date","DateTime",$false) 
$lList.Fields["Date"].Title="Date" 
$lList.Fields["Date"].Defaultvalue="[today]" 
$lList.Fields["Date"].Update() 
$lList.Update()
```

Comment: Great! It works like a charm!

Comment: that ([today]) is work on field setting in list setting also